# Laravel 5.3 Session not saving data

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I have the following two functions in my Controller which I use in the same way.

I am using the correct inputs, but the `setComplexity` does not save the `$complexity` to the session.

Any idea why this would be happening?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Complexity;
use App\Rating;
use Session;

class RatingController extends Controller
{
    public function setRating(Request $request){
        if(Session::getId() == $request->get('session_id')){
            if(session()->has('rating')){
                $rating = session()->get('rating');
            }else{
                $rating = new Rating();
            }
        }else{
            $rating = new Rating();
        }
        $rating->mystery_id = $request->get('mystery_id');
        $rating->rating = $request->get('rating');
        $rating->save();

        session()->put('rating' , $rating);
        return json_encode(['rating' => $rating]);
    }

    public function setComplexity(Request $request){
        if(Session::getId() == $request->get('session_id')){
            if(session()->has('complexity')){
                $complexity = session()->get('complexity');
            }else{
                $complexity = new Complexity();
            }
        }else{
            $complexity = new Complexity();
        }
        $complexity->mystery_id = $request->get('mystery_id');
        $complexity->rating = $request->get('rating');
        $complexity->save();

        session()->put('complexity' , $complexity);
        return json_encode(['complexity' => $complexity]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the `session_id` in the Request parameters?

Comment: I am calling this as an ajax call and want to check if in this session, a rating or a complexity has already been reported. The other way would be, to add a user or something... still, i am wondering why this is not working for the setComplexity function and it's working for the setRating...